# Angular QueryList changes

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a component "ProductList" that contains "Product" components.
When the list changes I want to remove old eventlistener and add a new one...........

```
@ViewChildren(ProductComponent) products: QueryList<any>;
```

Then I subscribe to the QueryList changes in ngAfterViewInit hook

```
this.products.changes.subscribe(products => {
 console.log(‘changes’, this.products.length);
});
```

The problem is that it fires twice when the querylist is updated.. once before the list is updated and once after.. ??

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to remove listeners and add new ones when the list changes. QueryList is updated as the new elements arrive.

See what the docs have to say about it:

> An unmodifiable list of items that Angular keeps up to date when the state of the application changes.

[Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList)

Comment: hmm.. but the list is not replaced right? Just updated with the new elements?

Comment: hmmm then why would the old eventlisteners be gone?

Comment: Did find out what the issue was... the component had a "loading" div... when that was added/removed from DOM it triggered the .changes.. might be a bug in the querlist.. ?